weird error while trying to connect to mongodb connection string gotten from atlas
I am trying to connect to mongodb using mongoose and a connection string from MongoDB atlas but I keep getting the error below:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'constructor')

I installed the latest version(8.7.3) and downgraded it to 7.6.0, which I used in a previous project. Both gave the same error.
Reading the connection string from .env and hard-coding it gave the same error.
Here's the code that is responsible for the connection. Any help will be appreciated
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import variables from '../variables';
import { logger } from '../utilities';

dotenv.config();

console.log('DB_URI', process.env.DATABASE_URL);

export const connect = async (): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    if (!process.env.DATABASE_URL) {
      throw new Error('DATABASE_URL not provided');
    }

    await mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.5n5aj.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0");
    console.log('DB connected successfully');
    logger.info(`DB is successfully connected`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('DB connection error>>', error);
    logger.error(`DB connection error ${error}`);
  }
};

export const disconnect = () => {
  if (!process.env.DATABASE_URL) {
    return;
  }
  mongoose.disconnect();
};


Have you narrowed down which line is causing the error?

Yes, it's happening inside mongoose.connect(uri). it is unable to read properly an URI passed in

Remove the console.log from outside,
The error is not happening in try/catch block I think,
check the imports
import variables from '../variables';
import { logger } from '../utilities';

also try this,
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, { 
  useNewUrlParser: true, 
  useUnifiedTopology: true 
})

